# Fetch desired ID contents from multiple servers

Tags: mapreduce, distributed-computing

Imagine I have a distributed system with 500 servers. I have a main database server that stores some metadata and each entry’s primary key is the content ID. The actual content that’s related to the content ID spreads across 500 servers. But not all contentID’s content is in the 500 servers yet. Say only half of them are on the 500 servers.

How could I find out the contentIDs that are not deployed to any one of the 500 servers yet?

I’m thinking using map reduce style way to solve this but not sure how would the process be like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context in the question:

- You can build a table in your database containing information about contentID to instance mapping.
- Whenever an instance has a data for the given content ID, it needs to make a call and register the contentID.
- If your instances can crash and you need to remove those content, you can implement health-check which will try to update your database every 30seconds~ 1 minute.

Now, whenever you need to access the instanceID for a given contentID and whether it has been loaded or not you can refer to the table above and check if the contentID has a instanceID with health-check time within 1 min.

Note: You can also consider using Zookeeper or In-Memory datastore like Redis for storing this data as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering!! Sounds like I would need an extra column in my main database “contentID, instanceID, deployed” like this? So when I need to know which IDs are not deployed yet, I just check the “deployed” column? 
One question I have is: since the content is already shattered to all the instances. Each of them would have a make a call to the main database to register the IDs it has. Is there a good way to make this batch write process faster?

Comment: You can consider using separate table to avoid locking the table containing metadata information. And given 500 instances its should be easily handled by database as updates/query will be distributed over 30sec to 60 seconds as discussed bringing the overall QPS.
In case of errors, you can use exponential backoff just in case database is struggling.